# AutoMapper map from source nested collection to another collection

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nested, viewmodel, automapper

EDIT: Title is incorrect, I am trying to map from a source list to a nested model's source list.

I am having trouble trying to map a list to another listed in a nested model. Kind of and un-flatten of sorts. The problem is I don't know how to do the mappings.

Here is my set up followed my failed attempts at mapping:

```
public class DestinationModel
{
    public DestinationNestedViewModel sestinationNestedViewModel { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationNestedViewModel
{
    public List<ItemModel> NestedList { get; set; }
}

public class SourceModel
{
    public List<Item> SourceList { get; set; }
}
```

Where Item and ItemModel already have a mapping defined between them

I can't do it this way...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceModel, DestinationModel>()
.ForMember(d => d.DestinationNestedViewModel.NestedList,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceList))
```

ERROR:

Expression 'd => d.DestinationNestedViewModel.NestedList' must resolve to top-level member.Parameter name: lambdaExpression

I then tried something like this:

```
.ForMember(d => d.DestinationNestedViewModel, 
 o => o.MapFrom(t => new DestinationNestedViewModel { NestedList = t.SourceList }))
```

The problem there is 
    **NestedList = t.SourceList**.
They each contain different elements, **ItemModel** and **Item** respectively. So, they need to be mapped.

How do I map this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but I think you need to create a mapping from Item to ItemModel, so AutoMapper knows how to map Item objects to ItemModel objects.

Comment: There is a mapping already defined between Item and ItemModel, but the mapping is not being triggered because NestedList belongs to a DestinationModel
 which in turn belongs to DestinationNestedViewModel. Automapper can not handle 2 tiers of models when mapping (at least not the way I have tried it)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemModel>();

/* Create a mapping from Source to Destination, but map the nested property from 
   the source itself */
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceModel, DestinationModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DestinationNestedViewModel, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

/* Then also create a mapping from Source to DestinationNestedViewModel: */
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceModel, DestinationNestedViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NestedList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SourceList));
```

Then all you should have to do is call `Mapper.Map` between `Source` and `Destination`:

```
Mapper.Map<SourceModel, DestinationModel>(source);
```

Comment: first map the collections of both objects.. then define the mappings for the individual objects within those collections.. automapper is so cool